# How to create cake php project using composer

Tags: php, cakephp

Being new in CakePHP, I can't understand how to create the project folder using composer. I tried to run the install using composer, but it's showing me errors.

> Installing cakephp/app (3.0.3)
>     - Installing cakephp/app (3.0.3)
>       Loading from cache
>
> Created project in C:\xampp\htdocs\cphp\app Loading composer
>   repositories with package information Installing dependencies
>   (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an
>   installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extensi on intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/ca kephp[3.0.0, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-alpha1,
>   3.0.0-alpha2, 3.0.0-beta1, 3.0. 0-beta2, 3.0.0-beta3, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.1.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].

Comment: There error message clearly states what the problem is: "Problem 1 - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extensi on intl is missing from your system"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message pretty much says it all:

> The requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.

This module is required for all Cake 3.x versions, that's why it's repeated so many times (all the different versions show the same problem).

By default, XAMPP (which you seem to be using) comes shipped with it, but it may not be enabled. Open `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` with a text editor like notepad and then uncomment (remove the semicolon at the beginning) the line loading the intl extension, so it just reads: `extension=php_intl.dll`.

Try again after that, Composer should then continue checking your system and either install Cake or throw any additional problems your way.